# JavaScript OAuth2 library

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0

Is there a consumer OAuth2 javascript library that works both in node.js and the browser?
I'm working on a common.js module that needs to work in both enviroments and have OAuth2 consume capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

For now the Google Web Toolkit OAuth2 library is available separately.

https://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/